# How do I access a postgres table from pyspark on IBM's Data Science Experience?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science-experience, dsx

Here is my code:

```
uname = "xxxxx" 
pword = "xxxxx" 
dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver" 
table = "xxxxx"
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", dbUrl).option("dbtable",table).option("user", uname).option("password", pword).load()
```

I'm getting a "No suitable driver" error after adding the postgres driver jar (%Addjar -f https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar).  Is there a working example of loading data from postgres in pyspark 2.0 on DSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make use of pixiedust package manager to install the postgres driver on spark service level.

http://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/Package-Manager.html

Since Pixiedust is only supported on spark 1.6 , run

`pixiedust.installPackage("https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar")`

Once you install this, restart kernel and then 
Switch to spark 2.0 to run your postgres connection to get spark dataframe using sparksession.

`uname = "username"`

`pword = "xxxxxx"`

`dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:10635/compose?user="+uname+"&password="+pword`

`table = "tablename"`

`Df = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(url=dbUrl,database='compose',dbtable=table).load()`

`houseDf.take(1)`

Working Notebook:-

https://apsportal.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/8b220408-6fc7-48a9-8350-246fbbf10ac8/view?access_token=7297af80b2e4109087a78365e7df3205f6ed9d0840c0c46d2208bc00ed0b0274

Thanks,
Charles.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide driver option

```
option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how I could do this on a notebook in Data Science Experience?